# How to get started on Information Extraction?

Tags: math, machine-learning, nlp, information-extraction

Could you recommend a training path to start and become very good in Information Extraction. I started reading about it to do one of my hobby project and soon realized that I would have to be good at math (Algebra, Stats, Prob). I have read some of the introductory books on different math topics (and its so much fun). Looking for some guidance. Please help.

Update: Just to answer one of the comment. I am more interested in Text Information Extraction.

Comment: What kind of information (clusters? association rules? novelty? sequential patterns?)? What kind of data (time series? transactions? images? text?)? What kind of analysis? Which domain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Just to answer one of the comment. I am more interested in Text Information Extraction.

Depending on the nature of your project, [Natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), and [Computational linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_linguistics) can both come in handy -they provide tools to measure, and extract features from the textual information, and apply training, scoring, or classification.

Good introductory books include [OReilly's Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) (chapters on "searching, and ranking", Document filtering, and maybe decision trees).

Suggested projects utilizing this knowledge: POS (part-of-speech) tagging, and named entity recognition (ability to recognize names, places, and dates from the plain text). You can use Wikipedia as a training corpus since most of the target information is already extracted in infoboxes -this might provide you with some limited amount of measurement feedback.

The other big hammer in IE is search, a field not to be underestimated. Again, OReilly's book provides some introduction in basic ranking; once you have a large corpus of indexed text, you can do some really IE tasks with it. Check out [Peter Norvig: Theorizing from data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU8DcBF-qo4) as a starting point, and a very good motivator -maybe you could reimplement some of their results as a learning exercise.

As a fore-warning, I think I'm obligated to tell you, that information extraction is *hard*. The first 80% of any given task is usually trivial; however, the difficulty of each additional percentage for IE tasks are usually growing exponentially -in development, and research time. It's also quite underdocumented -most of the high-quality info is currently in obscure white papers ([Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) is your friend) -do check them out once you've got your hand burned a couple of times. But most importantly, do not let these obstacles throw you off -there are certainly big opportunities to make progress in this area.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the excellent book [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) by Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze. It covers a broad area of issues which form a great and up-to-date (2008) basis for Information Extraction and is available online in full text (under the given link).

Comment: Yes, but as I write in my answer, I believe it covers areas that form a solid basis for Information Extraction. You asked for a place to start.

Comment: I was going to recommend the Introduction to Information Retrieval book, but I only have the PDF and not the URL for where I found it.  Thanks for posting the link.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you take a look at the [Natural Language Toolkit (nltk)](http://www.nltk.org) and the [NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book).  Both are available for free and are great learning tools.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be good at math to do IE just understand how the algorithm works, experiment on the cases for which you need an optimal result performance, and the scale with which you need to achieve target accuracy level and work with that. You are basically working with algorithms and programming and aspects of CS/AI/Machine learning theory not writing a PhD paper on building a new machine-learning algorithm where you have to convince someone by way of mathematical principles why the algorithm works so I totally disagree with that notion. There is a difference between practical and theory - as we all know mathematicians are stuck more on theory then the practicability of algorithms to produce workable business solutions. You would, however, need to do some background reading both books in NLP as well as journal papers to find out what people found from their results. IE is a very context-specific domain so you would need to define first in what context you are trying to extract information - How would you define this information? What is your structured model? Supposing you are extracting from semi and unstructured data sets. You would then also want to weigh out whether you want to approach your IE from a standard human approach which involves things like regular expressions and pattern matching or would you want to do it using statistical machine learning approaches like Markov Chains. You can even look at hybrid approaches.

A standard process model you can follow to do your extraction is to adapt a data/text mining approach:

> pre-processing - define and standardize your data to extraction from various or specific sources cleansing your data
>
> segmentation/classification/clustering/association - your black box where most of your extraction work will be done
>
> post-processing - cleansing your data back to where you want to store it or represent it as information

Also, you need to understand the difference between what is data and what is information. As you can reuse your discovered information as sources of data to build more information maps/trees/graphs. It is all very contextualized.

standard steps for: input->process->output

If you are using Java/C++ there are loads of frameworks and libraries available you can work with.

Perl would be an excellent language to do your NLP extraction work with if you want to do a lot of standard text extraction.

You may want to represent your data as XML or even as RDF graphs (Semantic Web) and for your defined contextual model you can build up relationship and association graphs that most likely will change as you make more and more extractions requests. Deploy it as a restful service as you want to treat it as a resource for documents. You can even link it to taxonomized data sets and faceted searching say using Solr.

Good sources to read are:

- Handbook of Computational Linguistics and Natural Language Processing
- Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing
- Information Extraction Applications in Prospect
- An Introduction to Language Processing with Perl and Prolog
- Speech and Language Processing (Jurafsky)
- Text Mining Application Programming
- The Text Mining Handbook
- Taming Text
- Algorithms of Intelligent Web
- Building Search Applications
- IEEE Journal

Make sure you do a thorough evaluation before deploying such applications/algorithms into production as they can recursively increase your data storage requirements. You could use AWS/Hadoop for clustering, Mahout for large scale classification amongst others. Store your datasets in MongoDB or unstructured dumps into jackrabbit, etc. Try experimenting with prototypes first. There are various archives you can use to base your training on say Reuters corpus, tipster, TREC, etc. You can even check out alchemy API, GATE, UIMA, OpenNLP, etc.

Building extractions from standard text is easier than say a web document so representation at pre-processing step becomes even more crucial to define what exactly it is you are trying to extract from a standardized document representation.

Standard measures include *precision, recall, f1 measure* amongst others.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the people who recommend reading Programming Collective Intelligence. If you want to do anything of even moderate complexity, you need to be good at applied math and PCI gives you a false sense of confidence. For example, when it talks of SVM, it just says that libSVM is a good way of implementing them.

Now, libSVM is definitely a good package but who cares about packages. What you need to know is why SVM gives the terrific results that it gives and how it is fundamentally different from Bayesian way of thinking ( and how Vapnik is a legend).

IMHO, there is no one solution to it. You should have a good grip on Linear Algebra and probability and Bayesian theory.  Bayes, I should add, is as important for this as oxygen for human beings ( its a little exaggerated but you get what I mean, right ?).  Also,  get a good grip on Machine Learning.  Just using other people's work is perfectly fine but the moment you want to know why something was done the way it was, you will have to know something about ML.

Check these two  for that :

http://pindancing.blogspot.com/2010/01/learning-about-machine-learniing.html

http://measuringmeasures.com/blog/2010/1/15/learning-about-statistical-learning.html

http://measuringmeasures.com/blog/2010/3/12/learning-about-machine-learning-2nd-ed.html

Okay, now that's three of them :) / Cool

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia [Information Extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction) article is a quick introduction.

At a more academic level, you might want to skim a paper like [Integrating Probabilistic Extraction Models and Data Mining to Discover Relations and Patterns in Text](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~culotta/pubs/culotta06integrating.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.complexityintelligence.com) if you need enterprise grade NER service. Developing a NER system (and training sets) is a very time consuming and high skilled task.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little off topic, but you might want to read Programming Collective Intelligence from O'Reilly.  It deals indirectly with text information extraction, and it doesn't assume much of a math background.